# Не открывается приложение kivy на android

Tags: python, android, opencv, kivy

Делаю приложение для android. Использую kivy и opencv. Пытался просто открыть камеру на телефоне по нажанию кнопки, но приложение вообще не запускается (вылетает на логотипе). Собирал APK с помощью buildozer. Вот код:

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import cv2

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.btn = Button(text="Camera")
        self.btn.bind(on_press=self.press)
        return self.btn

    def press(self, instance, **kwargs):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 24)
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 600)
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)
        while True:
            ret, img = cap.read()
            img = cv2.flip(img, 1)
            cv2.imshow("camera", img)
            if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27:  # Клавиша Esc
                break
        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Разрешение дали на использование камеры?

Comment: Кстати а где вы взяли cv2 под python для андроида?

Comment: Разве OpenCV не работает на android?

Comment: Пока я видел только у Pydroid приложения

Comment: Разве OpenCV не работает на android? Вы не правильно вопрос ставите, OpenCV для Андроида есть, вы ведь его из Python используете.